# How to aggregate a metric and plot groups separately

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['year'] = [2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011]
df['month'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
df['after'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
df['campaign'] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
df['sales'] = [10000,11000,12000,10500,10000,9500,7000,8000,5000,6000,6000,7000]
df['date_m'] = pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.month.astype(str))
```

And I want to make a line plot grouped by month and campaign, so I have tried this code:

```
df['sales'].groupby(df['date_m','campaign']).mean().plot.line()
```

But I get this error message `KeyError: ('date_m', 'campaign')`. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Plotting is typically dependant upon the shape of the DataFrame.
- `.groupby` creates a long format DataFrame, which is great for `seaborn`
- `.pivot_table` creates a wide format DataFrame, which easily works with `pandas.DataFrame.plot`

### [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the DataFrame

- `df['sales'].groupby(...)` is incorrect, because `df['sales']` selects one column of the dataframe; none of the other columns are available
- `.groupby` converts the DataFrame into a long format, which is great for plotting with [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html).

  - Specify the `hue` parameter to separate by `'campaign'`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# perform groupby and reset the index
dfg = df.groupby(['date_m','campaign'])['sales'].mean().reset_index()

# display(dfg.head())
      date_m  campaign  sales
0 2011-01-01         0  10000
1 2011-01-01         1   7000
2 2011-02-01         0  11000
3 2011-02-01         1   8000
4 2011-03-01         0  12000

# plot with seaborn
sns.lineplot(data=dfg, x='date_m', y='sales', hue='campaign')
```

[image]

### [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) the DataFrame

- `.pivot_table` shapes the DataFrame correctly for plotting with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), and it has an aggregation parameter.

  - The DataFrame is shaped into a wide format.

```py
# pivot the dataframe into the correct shape for plotting
dfp = df.pivot_table(index='date_m', columns='campaign', values='sales', aggfunc='mean')

# display(dfp.head())
campaign        0     1
date_m                 
2011-01-01  10000  7000
2011-02-01  11000  8000
2011-03-01  12000  5000
2011-04-01  10500  6000
2011-05-01  10000  6000

# plot the dataframe
dfp.plot()
```

[image]

### Plotting with `matplotlib` directly

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
for v in df.campaign.unique():
    # select the data based on the campaign
    data = df[df.campaign.eq(v)]
    # this is only necessary if there is more than one value per date
    data = data.groupby(['date_m','campaign'])['sales'].mean().reset_index()

    ax.plot('date_m', 'sales', data=data, label=f'{v}')
plt.legend(title='campaign')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Notes

- Package versions:

  - `pandas v1.2.4`
  - `seaborn v0.11.1`
  - `matplotlib v3.3.4`

Comment: Thank you @Trenton McKinney, the answer works fine. Just a question, is it possible that only with matplotlib?

Comment: @Alexis The backend for pandas is matplotlib. That's the pivot_table implementation. Seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib. So both options are using matplotlib. Another option using matplotlib directly has been added, but it is more cumbersome.

Comment: Hello @Trenton McKinney, thank you very much for your answer and time, it's quite interesting that you have to add each strata one by one with a for loop. That clarified some questions I had over grouped variables. Again, thank you and have a great week!